# App to download all links on a page

Tags: android, open-source, firefox, download-manager

There's a webpage with download links. I need to download all the files listed on it - there are hundreds. Is there an open source app or browser add-on that can do this?

Comment: Just an idea and not a software recommendation. You could open the web console and trigger click on all download links per js. Something like this: $('.some_identifier').trigger('click')

Comment: Sounds interesting, I'll investigate and try that. Thanks

Comment: Just learn some simple shell scripting if you do these stuff a lot. It's trivial to get the links in a page (use `pup` or `wget`),  filter them (with `ripgrep`), and finally feed them to a downloader like `aria2c`.

Comment: You can also use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-selected-links/kddpiojgkjnpmgiegglncafdpnigcbij) to copy the links in the text selected.

Comment: Python has some pretty robust tools liek `requests` for making HTTP requests to download  things like html pages or linked files, and things like beautifulsoup for parsing HTML. Github probably also has some scripts made by other people that you could use as a starting point

Answer (score 1):

I searched around for you and found a few things that might be of help first I found an extension that you can use on chrome that would help with  you're situation just in case you're on the computer [simple mass downloader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-mass-downloader/abdkkegmcbiomijcbdaodaflgehfffed?hl=en-US)

I also found an app that might be of help check it out and see if it helps! [HERE!](https://www.groovypost.com/reviews/android-download-files-websites-downloader-app/)

Answer (score 0):

> [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/downthemall/) lets you download all the links or images on a website

I haven't done this in a while though.

I used to use a link sidebar extension, but it's not supported any more.